# Best JSON Data Points for $N/MultistrokeGestureRecognizer-iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am attempting to use the Objective-C [MultistrokeGestureRecognizer-iOS](https://github.com/britg/MultistrokeGestureRecognizer-iOS) library to detect what shape the user is drawing on the screen of their device. This library uses the [$N Multistroke Recognizer](https://depts.washington.edu/aimgroup/proj/dollar/ndollar.html)'s algorithm for determining the correlation between a user's drawing and glyphs written in JSON.

I have tried to determine when a user draws a Circle, Square, Triangle, or Diamond based on the float returned by the `WTMGlyphDetector`, but it seems to always return horribly inaccurate results.

For example, when simply drawing a dot on the screen, it will return a higher similarity to a diamond than when a user actually attempts to draw an accurate diamond.

I have tried to use a couple different complexity levels of JSON to see if the results would change. For example, with the Square shape, I started off with this JSON object:

```
 [
   [
     [ 27,19], [348,19], [347,343], [22,344], [23,18]
   ]
 ]
```

[image: First Picture]
Which did not seem to return the results I wanted, probably because it was far too vague. I switched to a much more detailed JSON Object like this one:

```
[
  [
    [226, 12], [ 285, 300], [ 214, 12], [ 443, 26], [ 451, 29], [ 102, 111],
    [196, 297], [ 394, 299], [ 223, 297], [ 95, 302], [ 108, 87], [ 176, 13], 
    [ 487, 299], [ 449, 28], [ 103, 99], [ 253, 12], [ 369, 12], [ 458, 269], 
    [ 150, 297], [ 287, 12], [ 459, 269], [ 216, 297], [ 156, 297], [ 118, 16], 
    [ 116, 306], [ 236, 300], [ 232, 299], [ 115, 16], [ 399, 15], [ 243, 300], 
    [ 307, 12], [ 425, 299], [ 107, 89], [ 98, 297], [ 128, 303], [ 101, 284],
    [ 246, 300], [ 460, 269], [ 376, 299],  [ 163, 297], [ 452, 29], [ 109, 65],
    [ 461, 294], [ 148, 299], [ 114, 16], [ 143, 300], [ 450, 29], [ 256, 300], 
    [ 453, 86], [ 136, 301], [ 113, 16], [ 111, 55], [ 147, 15], [ 456, 106],
    [ 185, 297], [ 173, 297], [ 121, 305], [ 157, 14], [ 322, 299], [ 495, 299], 
    [ 302, 300], [ 473, 299], [ 112, 39], [ 494, 299], [ 340, 12]
  ]
]
```

[image: Second Picture]
Which still returned poor results. I also tried loading just one JSON object compared to loading all four, and there did not seem to be a noticeable difference in the quality of the the result returned.

Am I using the library incorrectly? Is there a preferable setup in terms of accuracy of the JSON objects and/or how many of them you load into the `WTMGlyphDetector`?

Comment: Please consider adding photos of your objects for more detailed reference. If SO doesn't allow the upload just put them in a link.

Comment: Did you consider the possibility that the library may just inaccurate?

Comment: @JulianE. It is possible that the library is inaccurate, but judging from the data found at the [$N Multistroke Recognizer](https://depts.washington.edu/aimgroup/proj/dollar/ndollar.html) site I do not believe that it is.

Comment: Hm. But you are passing the correct points in. It should be accurate. Well, did you try printing out the points the user inputs using the NSLog("") function?

Comment: @JulianE. Yes I did, and I was also sure to clear the points the WTMGlyphDetector has stored every time they start drawing a new glyph.

Comment: And were the points accurate? Because that would affect the whole question. If the points were okay, the it's the matching algorithm thats not working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: I found a pretty good balance

Using [Plotly](http://plot.ly) I graphed out all of the JSON points and tried several different styles of writing the JSON until I found something that works. At first I tried using very complex shapes with tons of points, as shown above. These complex JSON Objects were generated using an app I built that printed out JSON objects that the user drew on the screen, solely for the purpose of spitting out the JSON I needed to make the WTMGlyphDetector function properly.

Next I tried using simple data generated in an app bundled with the MultistrokeGestureRecognizer-iOS GitHub repo, but only after using [Plotly](http://plot.ly) did I find out (much later) that this app outputted the data upside down! I manually reversed all of the datapoints and found that the app generally now worked.

I found that the scores returned by the WTMGlyphDetector was somewhere in the range between 2 and 3 when drawn properly and between 1 and 2 when drawn incorrectly. I decided to use 1.75 as my threshold for properly drawn shapes because I found (for the most part while testing) that this was the sweet spot that separated the bad/incorrect drawings from the actual attempts.

The only downside to the WTMGlyphDetector is that it takes the shapes in quite literally. For example, if you  drew a triangle and then went past the tip as follows:

[image]

The WTMGlyphDetector would not be able to identify this shape properly (only would work a percentage of the time).

Anyhow, I hope this write-up helps anyone who encounters the same issue as I did.

**TL;DR**: Simple JSON objects are better, avoid the bundled point generator and use a service such as [Plotly](http://plot.ly) instead. From my results, a float over 1.75 meant that the user drew it correctly, and below 1.75 means they drew it incorrectly.